# No route matches - Rails 4.0 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

So I am writing some API controllers that return and deal with json. One particular is a sessions controller. I set up the routes as such:

**Note:** (I am only showing you the destroy method cause that's the only one I am having issues with...)

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resource :users
      resources :sessions
    end
  end
```

Then I have routes such as:

```
   api_v1_sessions GET    /api/v1/sessions(.:format)          api/v1/sessions#index
                    POST   /api/v1/sessions(.:format)          api/v1/sessions#create
 new_api_v1_session GET    /api/v1/sessions/new(.:format)      api/v1/sessions#new
edit_api_v1_session GET    /api/v1/sessions/:id/edit(.:format) api/v1/sessions#edit
     api_v1_session GET    /api/v1/sessions/:id(.:format)      api/v1/sessions#show
                    PATCH  /api/v1/sessions/:id(.:format)      api/v1/sessions#update
                    PUT    /api/v1/sessions/:id(.:format)      api/v1/sessions#update
                    DELETE /api/v1/sessions/:id(.:format)      api/v1/sessions#destroy
```

And finally I have destroy code that looks like this, for `api/v1/sessions#destroy`:

```
    def destroy
      @user = User.find_by auth_token: param[:auth_token]
      return invalid_user_crendentials unless @user

      cookies.delete(@user.auth_token)
      render json: { user_id: @user.id }, status: 200
    end
```

Then I wrote the following spec tests for this particular action:

```
 context "Destroy a session" do
    it "should NOT destroy a session" do
        post :destroy
        response.response_code.should == 401
    end

    it "should NOT destroy a session with invalid token" do
        post :destroy, auth_token: '34534534'
        response.response_code.should == 401
    end

    it "should destroy a session based on valid data" do
        post :destory, auth_token: @user.auth_token
        json = JSON.parse response.body
        json.to_json.should have_json_path('user_id')
        response.response_code.should == 200
    end
  end
```

But when I run it I get:

```
No route matches {:auth_token=>"34534534", :controller=>"api/v1/sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
 No route matches {:auth_token=>"QfEg4oa0UdhJF4K1VIBADg", :controller=>"api/v1/sessions", :action=>"destory"}
No route matches {:controller=>"api/v1/sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
```

How does no route match? at all?

Comment: are you using Webmock or VCR or something to stub out requests in your tests?

Comment: FactoryGirl is what I use to create the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `post` to `delete`

```
context "Destroy a session" do
  it "should NOT destroy a session" do
      delete :destroy
      response.response_code.should == 401
  end

  it "should NOT destroy a session with invalid token" do
      delete :destroy, auth_token: '34534534'
      response.response_code.should == 401
  end

  it "should destroy a session based on valid data" do
      delete :destory, auth_token: @user.auth_token
      json = JSON.parse response.body
      json.to_json.should have_json_path('user_id')
      response.response_code.should == 200
  end
end
```

You can see in your `rake routes` output that your destroy action only accepts `delete` requests:

`DELETE /api/v1/sessions/:id(.:format)      api/v1/sessions#destroy`

It's also looking for an `:id` param. I think you want to change `param[:auth_token]` to `param[:id]` in your controller and `auth_token` to `id` in your spec.

Comment: Changed `post` to `delete` and I got - the exact same errors as I posted above.

Comment: I don't have an ID I am passing in, I am creating sessions via cookies and storing a user generated auth_token in the cookie ...

Comment: I understand, but your url is putting whatever comes after `/api/vi/sessions/` into `param[:id]`. If the naming is that important to you, you'll have to specify that for the route.

Comment: I go the idea from https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo/blob/master/app/controllers/api/sessions_controller.rb hence why I am passing in auth token .... and their routes don't seem to be abnormal ... so how can they pass in auth_token? where as I can't (routes: https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo/blob/master/config/routes.rb) am I missing something?

Comment: Their routes are completely different to yours - you have a session resource, they do not.

Comment: Are you saying that if I do not have a session resource I can just pass in what ever I want? that doesn't make sense to me ...

Comment: All we're saying is that you have a route that's url takes whatever is at the end of it and puts it into `param[:id]`. What you do with that is up to you. PS: the example project you're looking at set up `:auth_token` here https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth-rails-demo/blob/2a71356705cd93c8b5e001531cf0d7716e4710fe/config/initializers/devise.rb#L195 but they're using `devise` and their routes are totally different.

Comment: interesting I missed that. Sessions don't have an id .. that I know of, unless it could be the user id ...

Comment: You are coupling the name `:id` with the behavior of your session. They are completely different things. When rails constructs routes, it doesn't care that you're building sessions. `:id` is the default matcher name for the route you declared. It could just as easily be called `:asdf` and nothing would change except whatever was matched would be stored in `params[:asdf]` instead of `params[:id]`

Answer (score 1):

Your routes are all expecting an `id` parameter to be passed in.

```
DELETE /api/v1/sessions/:id
```

Your tests are passing in an `auth_token` instead. Change the tests to pass in an `id`.

Note: Your tests should indeed be `delete :destroy` instead of `post`, and your third test also has a typo in `:destroy`.